# what is this card game called?

Tags: identify-this-game

It's a game for 4 players. It has a board similar to Crib, but shaped differently. Each player has 4 pegs that start off the board.

You deal cards to each player. You can get your peg into play if you get an A, 2, or J. You then try to move the pegs around the board to get them safetly into your house. Other players try to land on your peg to knock them off the board.

If you get a K, you can kill someone else's peg by putting your peg there. Once you safetly get your pegs into your house, you are the partner of the player kitty corner to you. The team that gets all 8 pegs safely into their houses win.

What is this  game called?

Answer (score 1):

You seem to describe the game **[Dog](https://boardgamegeek.com/boardgame/2633/dog)**: 2 vs 2 parcheesi with cards instead of dice.